# Formal expansion of matrices using Maple or Mathematica

Tags: matrices, maple, mathematica

I'd like to evaluate some powers of sum of matrices, say I would like to evaluate $\left(A+B\right)^{n}$ with $A$ and $B$ some matrices. Since I'd like to go to high order, I'd like to use Maple or Mathematica to do that, but is there a way ?

To be more precise, how to calculate non-commutative product of commutative sum of objects in Maple or Mathematica ?

Of course, I want the formal expansion, for instance I want to calculate $\left(A+B\right)^{2}$ and get $$\left(A+B\right)\cdot\left(A+B\right)=A\cdot A+A\cdot B+B\cdot A+B\cdot B$$
at this level I do not need software, but at high order it would be convenient to have some. At no point I want to define what are $A$ or $B$.

Comment: There's a simple general formula: $(A + B)^n$ is the sum over all $2^n$ of the words of length $n$ in the alphabet $\{A, B\}$, interpreted as matrix products. For $n = 2$, the four strings are $AA, AB, BA, BB$, so $(A + B)^2 = A^2 + AB + BA + B^2$. In the special case that $A, B$ commute, the formula simplifies to a binomial expression: $\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} A^k B^{n - k}$.

Comment: @Travis Thanks for this trivial formula, this is absolutely not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an implementation of a non-commutating product but commutating sum in software. In fact my expression are far more complicated than the expansion of $(A+B)^{n}$. Technically, I just wonder whether there is a way for Maple to distribute the sum over the dot product between matrices.

Answer (score 0):

In Maple you could do something like this below, though you might find that it's also possible using the Physics package.

You can of course adjust and extend this kind of thing. Perhaps it'll get you started.

Maple's `expand` command already knows to treat the infix `&*` operator as noncommuting. We can create a short procedure to turn positive powers into explicit products involving that `&*` operator.

```
restart:

ncexpand:=proc(ee)                                                  
  subsindets(ee, `^`(anything,posint),
             proc(u)
               local i;
               `&*`(seq(op(1,u),i=1..op(2,u)));
             end proc);
end proc:

ncexpand( (A+B)^2 );

                        (A + B) &* (A + B)

expand( ncexpand( (A+B)^2 ) );

             (A &* A) + (A &* B) + (B &* A) + (B &* B)

ncexpand( (A+B)^3 );

                    (A + B) &* (A + B) &* (A + B)

ncexpand( (A+B)^3 + 7*(A+B)^2 );

        ((A + B) &* (A + B) &* (A + B)) + 7 ((A + B) &* (A + B))

S:=expand(ncexpand( (A+B)^3 + 7*(A+B)^2 )):
```

Let's check that:

```
eval( eval(S, [A=Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]),
               B=Matrix([[1,1],[2,2]])]),
      `&*`=`.` );

                            [291    369]
                            [          ]
                            [615    783]

eval( (A+B)^3 + 7*(A+B)^2,
      [A=Matrix([[1,2],[3,4]]),
       B=Matrix([[1,1],[2,2]])] );

                            [291    369]
                            [          ]
                            [615    783]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is not what I want. I want to treat formal objects, not arrays of numbers. How does your proc works with formal entries A and B not specified ?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the first block of code in Acer's Answer. That deals with formal objects A and B, not arrays of numbers. The second block of code is merely a check that the first block is correct.